# "User Model" functions in Laravel 5 don't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I migrate from laravel 4 to laravel 5. I modified User Model to make it compatible to laravel 5 User Model. The User model in Laravel 4 is like that:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    // some model relation functions..
    ...
    public function getLocationId()
    {
        return $this->location_id;
    }
}
```

I modified it and the new User model is like that now:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
    // some model relation functions (some changes for namespace)
    ...
    public function getLocationId()
    {
        return $this->location_id;
    }
}
```

However, getLocationId method is now problematic. The following line results in an error.

```
$auth_location_id = Auth::user()->getLocationId();
```

This is the error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2508:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getLocationId()
```

How can I make the method compatible to laravel 5? Thanks..

**Update:**

`$auth_location_id = Auth::user()->getLocationId;` works but returns empty!!

The line below works properly.

```
$auth_user_id = Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier();
```

Comment: What is the version of laravel, you are trying to update? 5.4? If so follow this link [https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php)

Comment: @zgabievi Yes, it is 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding, and short experience with Laravel, all I do is just to use:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

Then have my Model as:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function getLocationId()
    {
        return $this->location_id;
    }
}
```

So I may be safe to assume, at least because it works for me that all those contracts has be extended in the facade called when `....\User` is used.

> PS: this is just an illustration of how I currently use it in Laravel 5.2.*.

Hope this can help or lead you to the solution :)